# Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor

Tags: java, jsp, constructor

I am trying to read from a txt file and display it to a JSP file.

The Bean class gets `BufferedReader` from the `FileReaderz` class.
I create a `Beanx` object in jsp, but this is where I get stuck

```
 public class Beanx {
        public OuterBlock[] outer=new OuterBlock[100];
        public InnerBlock[] inner=new InnerBlock[100];

        /*public List<String> token1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        public List<String> token2 = new ArrayList<String>();*/
        //String[] token1;
        //String[] token2;

        public void callFileReaderz()throws Exception{
            FileReaderz fr=new FileReaderz();
            BufferedReader br1=FileReaderz.br;
            String[] token;
            int i=0,j=0;

            String line;
            while((line=br1.readLine())!=null){
                //System.out.println(line);
                token=line.split("#");
                //List<String> tokenList=Arrays.asList(token);
                if(token.length==5){
                    OuterBlock outerObj=new OuterBlock(token[0],Integer.parseInt(token[1]),Integer.parseInt(token[2]),
                            Float.parseFloat(token[3]),Float.parseFloat(token[4]));
                    this.outer[i++]=outerObj;
                    //System.out.println(token[0]);

                }
                else{
                    InnerBlock innerObj = new InnerBlock(token[0],token[1],Integer.parseInt(token[2]),
                            Integer.parseInt(token[3]),Float.parseFloat(token[4]),Float.parseFloat(token[5]));
                    this.inner[j++]=innerObj;

                }
            }
            br1.close();

        }

        public Beanx() throws Exception{
            this.callFileReaderz();
        }
    }


    public class FileReaderz {
        public static BufferedReader br;

        public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //public FileReaderz() throws FileNotFoundException{
            br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("database1.txt"));

    //System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }

}
```

When I try this in JSP page,

I get the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /dashBoard.jsp
Default constructor cannot handle exception type Exception thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
12: </head>
13: 
14: <body>
15: <%! Beanx bean=new Beanx(); %>
16: <div class="table-title">
17: <h3>Projects In Repository</h3>
18: </div>
```

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Beanx` class constructor throws `Exception` and you are creating `Beanx` object in declaration tag without handling the exception.

To resolve this issue just initialize the Beanx in declaration tag with `null` as below:

```
<%! Beanx bean =null; %>
```

And whenever you need to use this bean in scriptlet tag use the below code:

```
<% 
   try{

      bean=new Beanx();

      }catch(Exception e){
      //To do something
      }
 %>
```

This is same as in below java code:

```
class Main extends HttpServlet{

Beanx bean =null;

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    try{

      bean=new Beanx();

      }catch(Exception e){
      //To do something
      }
 }
}
```